# Delete images from Webspace with Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

i have a website where you can upload 3 Images, on that i decided to put a Delete button after a Image is Uploaded. The Images will get the name Image1.png Image2.jpg Image3.jpg.

i wanted to Delete Images on a click from my Webspace which get readen out with my database (Image1.png ....)

Now if i press Delete Image, the Website reloads & the Image keeps in the Webspace.

I will Provide the PHP and Javascript.

```
     ?>
      <button class=" deleteImages deleter" data-file=""<?php  echo $social['Bild1']; ?> data-type="Bild1" type="button">Bild Löschen</button>
      <?php
```

PHP

```
   <script>
    
    $(document).ready(()=>{
      $(".deleteImages").click((e)=>{
        var type = e.target.dataset.type;
        var file = e.target.dataset.file;
        var that = e;
       swal("Bist du sicher das du dieses Bild löschen willst?", {
        icon: "warning",
        buttons: {
          cancel: "Abbrechen",
          catch: {
            text: "Ja",
            value: "Yes",
          }
        },
    })
    .then((value) => {
      if(value == 'Yes'){
        $.ajax({
          type:"post",
          url:"delete_images.php",
          data:{type:type,file:file},
          success:(res)=>{
            if(res){
              window.location.reload();
            }
          }
        })
      }
    });
      })
    })
    </script>
```

Javascript

```
<?php
session_start();
include('admin/functions.php');

$obj = new Operations;
if($_POST){
    if($_SESSION['user_id']){
        $user_id = $_SESSION['user_id'];
        $users = $obj->getSingle('users','where id = "'.$user_id.'"');
        $username = strtolower($users['username']);
        $userdata_path = "users/".$username."/".$_POST['file'];
        unlink($userdata_path);
        $data = array(
            $_POST['type'] =>NULL
        );
        $profile = $obj->getSingle('profile','where user_id = "'.$user_id.'"');
        $obj->update('profile',$data,$profile['id']);
        echo 'success';

    }
}


?>
```

delete_images.php

Comment: `data-file=""<?php  echo $social['Bild1'];` - the quote marks need to be around the value, not before it: `data-file="<?php  echo $social['Bild1']";`. If you'd done some basic debugging with the JS you ought to have noticed it wasn't sending the value in the AJAX request (and that PHP is likely to have emitted a warning when unlink fails).